# Decomposing the element of a group with elements with coprime order

Tags: group-theory

I have the following exercise of group theory, it is supposed to be easy but I don't know how to show the existence of the elements that the problem is asking for. Can you give me some hints?

If $o(g)$ is the order of the element $g$, consider: $o(a) = mn$ with $\gcd (m, n) = 1$, show that $a = gh = hg$ for some $g, h \in G$ with $o(g) = m$ and $o(h) = n$.

Comment: Hint: for any element $g$ of finite order in any group and any positive integer $k$, $o(g^k) = o(g)/\gcd(m,k)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If $o(g)$ is the order of the element $g$, consider: $o(a) = mn$ with $\gcd (m, n) = 1$, show that $a = gh = hg$ for some $g, h \in G$ with $o(g) = m$ and $o(h) = n$.*

By Euclid's algorithm there are integers $s,t$ such that $$sm+tn=1.$$
Then $a=a^1=...$ Can you finish the proof now?

Comment: Ohhh thanks, I didn't think on Euclid's Algorithm, with this is clear.

Comment: Yes. It is used surprisingly often in University level mathematics.